# How do I get items by category wise

Tags: php, mysqli

Basically, I have a list of categories that I am iterating form mysqli

```
<div style="width:20%; float:left;">
            <h3>Categories</h3>
            <?php while($categories = $resultproductcategories->fetch_assoc()){?> 
            <div class="rows">
                <input type="button" name="<?php echo $categories['id'] ?>" value="<?php echo $categories['category?>" />;
            </div>
            <?php }?>
        </div>
```

Now what I want that if I press any category it should fetch data accordingly there is my code for fetching

```
    $stmtproducts = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM store_products sp INNER JOIN store_product_categories spc ON sp.product_category=spc.id WHERE sp.store_id=? AND sp.category=? LIMIT $count, 10");
$stmtproducts->bind_param("ii",$_SESSION['storeid'],$_POST['']);
$stmtproducts->execute();
$resultproducts = $stmtproducts->get_result();
$num=$resultproducts->num_rows;
echo $num;
$stmtproducts->close();
```

I am confused that if there was a specific name of input then I would have gotten it by `isset($_POST['name'])` but there is no specific name... I cannot think of how to send category to mysql.

```
<div id="divTransactional" style="width:70%;padding-left:5%; float:left;">
            <?php if($num>0) {?>
            <table class="table table-responsive table-hover" id="tableProducts">
                <h3>Products</h3>
                <tbody>
                    <?php for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++) { $products = $resultproducts->fetch_assoc();//while($products = $resultproducts->fetch_assoc()) {?>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Code: <?php echo $products['product_code'];?></td><td>Added On: <?php echo $products['product_date'];?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Name: <?php echo $products['product_name'];?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Category: <?php echo $products['category'];?></td> 
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Description: <?php echo $products['product_desc'];?></td> 
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Price: <?php echo $products['product_price'];?></td><td>Discount: <?php echo $products['product_discount'];?></td>  
                    </tr>

                    <tr style="width:100px; height:100px;">
                        <td><img src="../../uploads/store/products/<?php echo $products['product_image1'];?>"  style="width:100px; height:100px;"/></td>
                        <td><img src="../../uploads/store/products/<?php echo $products['product_image2'];?>"  style="width:100px; height:100px;"/></td>
                        <td><img src="../../uploads/store/products/<?php echo $products['product_image3'];?>"  style="width:100px; height:100px;"/></td>
                        <td><img src="../../uploads/store/products/<?php echo $products['product_image4'];?>"  style="width:100px; height:100px;"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php }?>
                </tbody>
                <?php if($num >= 10) { ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?count='.($count+10)?>">Next</a>&nbsp;
                <?php } ?>
                <?php $prev = $count - 10;
                if ($prev >= 0){?>
                <a href=" <?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?count='.$prev ?>">Previous</a>
                <?php }?>



            </table>
                <?php if($num >= 10) { ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?count='.($count+10)?>">Next</a>&nbsp;
                <?php } ?>
                <?php $prev = $count - 10;
                if ($prev >= 0){?>
                <a href=" <?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?count='.$prev ?>">Previous</a>
                <?php }?>
            <?php } ?>

        </div>
```

Comment: do you want to show the data or fetch it from the server ?

Comment: Fetch it from the server... lets say there are two categories iterated... category1 and category2... when I click category1 then only category1 data should be fetched

Comment: i would recommend using ajax for that.

Comment: Are you familiar with javascript and JQuery ?

Comment: not much but I also want category to append on url!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using Ajax to call the server with an Id in parameters. 

You need to add a class to your buttons and you do need to link a JS file and JQuery. here's an example.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="path/to/your/file.js"></script>
<div style="width:20%; float:left;">
    <h3>Categories</h3>
    <?php while($categories = $resultproductcategories->fetch_assoc()){?> 
    <div class="rows">
    <input type="button" name="<?php echo $categories['id'] ?>" value="<?php echo $categories['category']?>" class="btnCategory"/>;
</div>
<?php }?>
```

And then, using ajax you can call your php file that returns the value you need to fetch from your database.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.btnCategory').on('click', function(){
    var id = $this.attr('name');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'path/to/your/file.php',
        method: "GET",
        data: {category_id: id}, 
        success: function(data) {
            //This is the data fetch from the server
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(err) {
            console.error('An error occurred : ' + err);
        }
    });
});
});
```

And then, when your PHP file receive the parameter `$_GET['category_id']` you call your database.

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['category_id'])){
//An id was post in the url.
    $stmtproducts = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM store_products sp INNER JOIN store_product_categories spc ON sp.product_category=spc.id WHERE sp.store_id=? AND sp.category=? LIMIT $count, 10");
    $stmtproducts->bind_param("ii",$_SESSION['storeid'],$_POST['']);
    $stmtproducts->execute();
    $resultproducts = $stmtproducts->get_result();
    $num=$resultproducts->num_rows;
    $stmtproducts->close();
    $result = array('row_count' => $num, 'result' => $resultproducts);
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

And then you return a json array of your result. That's what I would do.
Hope it helps !

- Nic

Comment: You sir is the real MVP

Comment: Yeah one last thing can you modify it that I get the html of file.php and show it on current page?

Comment: you could, all you need to do is call the same page by removing the url params.

Comment: And adding a closing tag ?> for PHP

Comment: Well... not much of a jquery script-er me is. sorry could give demo?

Answer (score 0):

You asked for a demo, here it is .

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['category_id'])){
//An id was post in the url.
    $stmtproducts = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM store_products sp INNER JOIN store_product_categories spc ON sp.product_category=spc.id WHERE sp.store_id=? AND sp.category=? LIMIT $count, 10");
    $stmtproducts->bind_param("ii",$_SESSION['storeid'],$_POST['']);
    $stmtproducts->execute();
    $resultproducts = $stmtproducts->get_result();
    $num=$resultproducts->num_rows;
    $stmtproducts->close();
    $result = array('row_count' => $num, 'result' => $resultproducts);
    echo json_encode($result);
}
?>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:20%; float:left;">
<h3>Categories</h3>
<?php while($categories = $resultproductcategories->fetch_assoc()){?> 
<div class="rows">
    <input type="button" name="<?php echo $categories['id'] ?>" value="<?php echo $categories['category']?>" class="btnCategory"/>;
</div>
<?php }?>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.btnCategory').on('click', function(){
    var id = $this.attr('name');
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        data: {category_id: id}, 
        success: function(data) {
            //This is the data fetch from the server
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(err) {
            console.error('An error occurred : ' + err);
        }
    });
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: It give data on console perfectly how do I refresh the page with the new url?  manageproducts.php?category_id=21 this is through inspect element.

Comment: You don't just use the data it returns and play with it,

Comment: I do jquery stuff very less... And our institute didn't teach ajax!

Comment: the ajax request works, all you have to do is use the data it returns and change the data of your pages using html(), append() and prepend() function. i can't do all the work for you.

Comment: Yes I was thinking about that! But it wouldn't refresh the url wouldn't it?

Comment: No, it calls a new instance of the pages. in a second call.